# Methods in YUI module pattern don't show up in IDE structure view

Tags: javascript, netbeans, intellij-idea, moodle, yui3

I have made a YUI module a little like the code shown below, which is the recommended pattern for YUI3 stuff, both within YUI's own core files and within Moodle as per [here](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/How_to_create_a_YUI_3_module#YUI_3_Moodle_Module_quick_start).

The problem is that now I can't see any of the methods (such as initializer() and show() in the code below) in the IDE's file structure/navigator pane. It seems that the Y.extend() logic is too much to handle, despite previous use of YAHOO.lang.Extend() outside of the sandboxed pattern used below working fine.

Has anyone any suggestions as to how to fix this? Is it just my IDE (tried IntelliJ IDEA - [bug here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11642), and NetBeans)? Surely the YUI devs don't have this same problem do they?

```
YUI.add('moodle-local_hub-comments', function (Y) {

    var COMMENTSNAME = 'hub_comments';

    var COMMENTS = function () {
        COMMENTS.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    M.local_hub = M.local_hub || {};

    Y.extend(M.local_hub, Y.Base, {

        // Invisible property:
        event : null,

        // Invisible function:
        initializer : function (params) {
            // function code here
        },

        // Invisible function:
        show : function (e) {
            // function code here
        },

        // Invisible function:
        hide : function () {
            // function code here
        }

    }, {
        NAME : COMMENTSNAME,
        ATTRS : {
            commentids : {value : 450} 
        }
    });

}, '@VERSION@', {
    requires : ['base', 'overlay', 'moodle-enrol-notification']
    //Note: 'moodle-enrol-notification' contains Moodle YUI exception
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a possible bug with IntelliJ, with details [here](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-83862). Good to know that they at least in theory support it.

As a worksround, JSDoc can be added above the extends function like this:

```
/**
 * @class M.local_hub
 **/
Y.extend(M.local_hub, Y.Base, {
```

Which makes all the methods show up :)

Answer (score 0):

Every IDE I've ever seen (I've tried NetBeans, jEdit, Sublime, and at least four different Eclipse JS editors) has failed to display methods like your's in the outline view.  I know there's a ticket to fix the issue in Eclipse (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=266113), but I'm not holding my breath: this seems to be something that's very hard for IDEs to do.

If you wanted, you *could* always refactor your code to be more IDE-friendly, but you'd lose your encapsulation:

```
function initializer(e) {
   // function code here
}
function show() {
   // function code here
}
function hide {
   // function code here
}
function moodle-local_hub-comments (Y) {

    var COMMENTSNAME = 'hub_comments';

    var COMMENTS = function () {
        COMMENTS.superclass.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    M.local_hub = M.local_hub || {};


    Y.extend(M.local_hub, Y.Base, {

        event : null,

        initializer : initializer,

        show : show,

        hide : hide

    }
YUI.add('moodle-local_hub-comments', moodle-local_hub-comments, {
        NAME : COMMENTSNAME,
        ATTRS : {
            commentids : {value : 450} 
        }
    });

}, '@VERSION@', {
    requires : ['base', 'overlay', 'moodle-enrol-notification']
    //Note: 'moodle-enrol-notification' contains Moodle YUI exception
});
```

Comment: As a side note, Sublime has a kind of unique alternative to the outline view, which works with any code (because it's a graphical outline, and thus doesn't require code parsing).  Personally I just use Eclipse without outline view though.

Comment: Thanks, I did consider a similar structure to yours, but I need to work within Moodle's framework, so the structure above is kind of imposed upon me :( I di find a workaround however.

Comment: Interesting; I may finally have a reason to try IntelliJ now :-)